# XSL transformation exclude specific qname for cdata section?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm doing a xstl transformation where I want to keep a CDATA entry from source xml. Therefore I define the cdata-section-elements accordingly. BUT I have the same qname with an attribute `name="test"`. There I do NOT want to apply the cdata. How can I exclude this element?

.xml

```
<my:request><![CDATA[<foo...>]]>
<my:request>

<my:request name="test">
</my:request>
```

.xsl

```
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="my:request"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not possible to have an exception based on an attribute!

BUT!! If you insist an alternative solution then .. I would advise you to insert `<![CDATA[` for an element `my:request` which doesn't have attribute `name`.. refer my example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="http://www.w3.org/2001/something">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="my:request[not(@name)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

      <!--Insert CDATA-->
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#60;![CDATA['" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="']]&#62;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my:root xmlns:my="http://www.w3.org/2001/something">
  <my:request other="something">data</my:request>    
  <my:request name="test">data</my:request>
</my:root>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my:root xmlns:my="http://www.w3.org/2001/something">
  <my:request other="something"><![CDATA[data]]></my:request>    
  <my:request name="test">data</my:request>
</my:root>
```